# Inserir imagen em cada INPUT em PHP

Tags: php

Estou com dificuldade de inserir em cada input uma imagem. Abaixo está o formHabilitacao que tem os 02(dois) inputs.
--FORMHABILITACAO--

```
<tr >
    <td colspan="3">
    <div id="divUploadArquivoHabilitacao" >
            <form  id="frmUploadArquivoHabilitacao" name="frmUploadArquivoHabilitacao" method="post" action="../Business/uploadArquivoBO.php" 
            enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
                Arquivo digitalizado:<span class="style1">*</span>
                <input name="txtArquivo" id="txtArquivo" type="file"  />
                <input name="indiceArquivo" id="indiceArquivo" type="hidden" />
                <input name="nomeArquivo" id="nomeArquivo" type="hidden" />
                <input name="cpfArquivo" id="cpfArquivo" type="hidden" />
                <br>
                Arquivo digitalizado1:<span class="style1">*</span>
                <input name="txtArquivo[]" id="txtArquivo" type="file"  />
                <input name="indiceArquivo" id="indiceArquivo" type="hidden" />
                <input name="nomeArquivo" id="nomeArquivo" type="hidden" />
                <input name="cpfArquivo" id="cpfArquivo" type="hidden" />
            </form>         
    </div>  
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Nesse outro arquivo é onde ficar a regra para inserir as imagens.
---UPLOADARQUIVOBO---

```
$nomeArquivo = date('Y-m-d-H-i-s') ."-". (str_replace("-", "", str_replace(".", "", $_POST["cpfArquivo"])) );

if(empty($_FILES["txtArquivo"]["tmp_name"]) || $_FILES["txtArquivo"]["tmp_name"] == "none"){
   $msg="ERRO: Arquivo não reconhecido! <BR><BR> Se o problema persistir use outro Navegador(Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, Firefox).";
}
else if($_FILES["txtArquivo"]["size"] > 5242880){
    $msg="ERRO: Tamanho do Arquivo maior que o permitido: 5MB!";
}
else if($_FILES['txtArquivo']['type'] != "application/pdf"){
    $msg="ERRO: O Arquivo deve ser do tipo Adobe PDF ! <BR><BR> Se o problema persistir use outro Navegador(Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, Firefox).";
}
else{

for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["txtArquivo"]["name"]);$i++){
    $ext = substr($_FILES['txtArquivo']['name'], strlen($_FILES['txtArquivo']['name'])-4, strlen($_FILES['txtArquivo']['name'])[$i]);

    $tempFile = $_FILES['txtArquivo']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $targetPath = "../".SERVIDOR_ARQUIVO_TEMP;
    $targetFile =  $targetPath . strtolower($nomeArquivo) . $ext;

    if(move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFile)){
        $msg = "";
    } else {
        $msg = "Ocorreu um erro contate o Administrador.";
    }
    // $msg = $targetPath."__".$targetFile;
}
}

$arr["message"]=$msg;
$arr["content_type"]=$_FILES['txtArquivo']['type'];
$arr["nome_arquivo"]=$nomeArquivo . $ext;
session_start();
```

Comment: Só irá salvar caso os dois arquivos sejam validos ?